# xsl syntax for an xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following structure for a movies xml file

```
<movies>
 <movie>
    <genre>Drama</genre>
    <genre>Thriller</genre>
 </movie>
 ....
</movies>
```

Shouldn't this snippet for selecting every value of genre for each movie tag work ?

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>MOVIES</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
  <th>Genre</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="movies/movie">
<tr>
  <td>
  <xsl:for-each select="movies/movie/genre">

          <xsl:value-of select="genre"/>

</xsl:for-each>
  </td>

</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It shows nothing as ouput. Can anyone please point out the mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because of the selector in the nested `xsl:for-each`: the outer one iterates through `movies/movie`, so in the inner one you already are in a `movie` element, but you're selecting `movies/movie/genre`; that means you're looking for `/movies/movie/movies/movie/genre`. The `xsl:value-of` uses an incorrect selector as well.

The code should be (untested):

```
<xsl:for-each select="movies/movie">
<tr>
  <td>
  <!-- context element here is movie -->
  <xsl:for-each select="genre">
      <!-- context element here is genre -->
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <!-- Separate genres with a comma -->
      <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())">, </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

By the way (off-topic), the `bgcolor` attribute was deprecated in HTML 4 (a long time ago) :)
You should use `style` instead:

```
<tr style="background-color: #9acd32;">
```

Answer (score 2):

While sierrasdetandil's answer already gave you the solution for your problem at hand I'd like to provide an alternative using `apply-templates` instead of `for-each`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>MOVIES</h2>
                    <table>
                        <tr><th>Genre</th></tr>
                        <xsl:apply-templates />
                    </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="movies">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="movie">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="genre">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: can anyone of you answer my query at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423864/xsl-defining-in-xml

Answer (score 1):

**As simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <table><xsl:apply-templates/></table>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="movie">
     <tr>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </tr>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="genre"><td><xsl:apply-templates/></td></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<movies>
 <movie>
    <genre>Drama</genre>
    <genre>Thriller</genre>
 </movie>
</movies>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Drama</td>
      <td>Thriller</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```