# Linking XSD XML XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have 3 files movies_sch.xsd, movies_style.xsl and movies.xml.

Can anyone please suggest the linking/href or the namespace tags for all 3 so that I can get all 3 working together.

Code snippets can be seen  at [xsl defining in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13423864/xsl-defining-in-xml) No one was replying there, so reposted here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what platform you are on but I doubt there is a "the linking/href or the namespace tags for all 3 so that to get all 3 working together.". on the .NET platform you would use the XmlReader for loading the movies.xml file. The Xml reader would be set so that it uses XmlSchemaSet for validation. The schema set would contain movies_sch.xsd. Once you set this up you would load the movies_style.xsl file to XslCompiledTransform and then call Transform method providing the XmlReader you had created as the input and a file or XmlWriter as the output. This would be for me "linking the 3 files together" - probably around 10-15 lines of code total. 
If the Xml file never changes you can validate it once (e.g. in the Visual Studio) and skip setting validation with XmlReader if validation with Visual Studio works.